# touchesBegan - Only needs the last touch action - iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, touch

In

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

method I am doing some actions and in

```
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

method I'm doing some other action.

If I'm tapping 3 times the touchesBegan will call 3 times. What I want is if the user continuously taps only the last touch action should perform. Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a `UITapGestureRecognizer` instead, and disable it after the first tap.

Otherwise, you can use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` with a short delay in `touchesEnded:withEvent:` and `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:` in `touchesBegan:withEvent:`.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Iam using - (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)object1 withObject:(id)object2 method. How can I cancel Previous Perform Requests?

Comment: `[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(someSelector) object:nil]`

Comment: Remember that you need to be performing a selector after a delay, or cancelling won't have any effect.