# Get the last touch event on UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uievent

> Note: This is a question similar to what is asked here, but the
>   answer provided there is not exactly a solution in my case. The question's
>   objective is different too. Reference:
>   [touchesBegan - Only needs the last touch action - iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213332/touchesbegan-only-needs-the-last-touch-action-iphone)

I am trying to handle multiple touches in a `UIView`. I need to get the exact touch positions in order.

Currently, I am attaching a selector like this:

```
[myView addTarget:self action:@selector(touchBegan:withEvent:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

This is my handler,

```
- (void)touchBegan:(UIButton *)c withEvent:ev {
    UITouch *touch = [[ev allTouches] anyObject];
```

The problem here is that `[ev allTouches]` returns an `NSSet` that is unordered, so I am unable to get the exact last location of the touch event in case of multiple touches.

Is there a way I can get the last location in the case when multiple touches are handled?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? do u need continuous monitoring of touches like in case of drawing app? Or its just one touch and u wanna know exact point of touch?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I do not need continuous monitoring of the touch positions, but I need to detect all the touches with their last-touched `CGPoint`s and multiple touches must be supported.

Comment: try my answer posted below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always create a subclass of your View and override `hitTest` to get the exact touch point

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    debugPrint(point)
    return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
}
```

Here am just logging touch point. Just to show how it works with I have added `touchesBegan` in my ViewController and logged first touch point from touches set

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    debugPrint(touches.first)
}
```

Here is the console log for both

> (175.66667175293, 175.33332824707)
>
> Optional(
>   phase: Began tap count: 1 force: 0.000 window: ; layer = > view:
>   > location in window:
>   {175.66665649414062, 175.33332824707031} previous location in window:
>   {175.66665649414062, 175.33332824707031} location in view:
>   {175.66665649414062, 175.33332824707031} previous location in view:
>   {175.66665649414062, 175.33332824707031})

So hit test says, your touch point is (175.66667175293, 175.33332824707) while `touches.first` says location in view : {175.66665649414062, 175.33332824707031}
which are basically same.

**Can `hitTest` be used as replacement to `touchBegan`? No**.

Thats why I had asked in comments above what exactly are you trying to achieve. If you are looking for continuous monitoring of touches than `touchBegan`, `touchMove`, `touchEnd` are the delegates you should opt for, but if you are trying to monitor a single touch and find its exact touch point you can always make use of `hitTest`

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the post. But, when there are multiple touches, `touches.first` may contain any one of the random touch events as that set is not ordered.

Comment: @bijoy-thangaraj : I just used touch began to show you how it is in sync with hitTest. Idea was to use hitTest rather. So try using hitTest

Comment: @Bijoy Thangaraj : am glad I could be of help. Happy coding